# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

The problem is that when I click a product to add to the cart to checkout it shows all the products, including the prices and total, on the stripe session instead of the item I selected. When I go back into my terminal it states that the "items" property can't be found but it is shown in my "checkout.js" file

I have attached the checkout.js, server.js, and terminal result below:

**server.js**

```
require("dotenv").config()

// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_XXXXX');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

const itemToPriceMap = new Map  ([
   [1, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Black Sweatsuit" }],
   [2, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Grey Sweatsuit" }],
   [3, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Red Sweatsuit" }],
   [4, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Blue Sweatsuit" }],
   [5, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Black T-Shirt" }],
   [6, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Blue T-Shirt" }],
   [7, { priceId: 'price_XXXXX', name: "Purple T-Shirt" }],
]);

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: req.body.items.map(item => {
      const storeItem = itemToPriceMap.get(item.id)
      return {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: storeItem.name
          },
          unit_amount: storeItem.priceId
        },
        quantity: item.quantity,
      }
    }),
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
    automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

**checkout.js**

```
const button = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      items: [
        { id: 1, quantity:5 },
        { id: 2, quantity:5 },
        { id: 3, quantity:5 },
        { id: 4, quantity:5 },
        { id: 5, quantity:75 },
        { id: 6, quantity:75 },
        { id: 7, quantity:75 },
      ],
    }),
  })
  .then(res => {
    if (res.ok) return res.json()
    return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
  })
  .then(({ url }) => {
    window.location = url
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e.error)
  })
})
```

**terminal result**

```
/Volumes/REVITAL/REVITAL/In Progress/Kingdom Website/Kingdom Website /server/server.js:23
    line_items: req.body.items.map(item => {
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body` on your request object is `undefined` because you don't have any middleware to parse the body.  From [the Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) (emphasis added):

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. **By default, it is `undefined`**, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()`.

If you add this under `app.use(express.static('public'));` then it should work as expected:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: So I tried your method and it's returning the same thing but its saying the typeError is in "map" now. It should work since I created an array but it's not receiving the info

Comment: Someone explained to me that the 'map' is passing nothing but numbers that's why it isn't working. How can I fix that?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Can you post a new question with your current code and the new error, as it seems like you're encountering a separate issue now?

Comment: Sure going to do that right now

Comment: just posted a new question